# What is the song playing at the end of My Hero Academia season 4 episode 12?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

Can someone please help me find the song used in episode 12 of season 4. It starts at the 20:15 aprox when Chisaki is trying to convince Eri to come back and deku refuses that idea.

Answer (score 0):

The song is called Red Riot. It's the 9th song on the Season 4 playlist.
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pg38mEVKi6s